# How to save a new buffer to a new file with helm?

Tags: buffers, helm, save

(It's likely a dumb question as I'm new to emacs buffer saving commands.)

After creating and editing a new buffer (with a temp name "untitled"), I would like to save it to a new file (not overwriting existing file) by a single command.

I tried to call `save-buffer` and `write-file`, both triggered `helm-mode-basic-save-buffer` (as i installed `helm`). But after typing the new file name, it returned `Lisp error: (cl-assertion-failed (sel "Trying to exit with no candidates"))`

I found that I can do it using 2 commands (`rename-buffer` and then `write-file`), but is there an easier way to do it by just a single command?

Thanks.